# Laravel SQL server connection

Tags: sql-server, laravel, connection

I have laravel 7.3, and sql server 16,

i need to connect to the database sql server, but i have this error :

SQLSTATE = 08001 error- No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

and there is the .env file

```
DB_CONNECTION=sqlsrv
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1/instancename
DB_PORT=1433
DB_DATABASE=Database
DB_USERNAME=sa
DB_PASSWORD=12345678`
```

But when i use the simple php file to connect the connexion is ok.

this is the php script :

```
<?php 
$serverName = "127.0.0.1/instancename";
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"Database", "UID"=>"sa", "PWD"=>"12345678");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

if( $conn ) {
echo "Connexion établie.<br />";
}else{
echo "La connexion n'a pu être établie.<br />";
die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));

}
?>
```

Manny  thanks for your help

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? How is this related to [tag:connexion]?

Answer (score 0):

**You can use this method**
Firstly add your sql server configuration in **`config/database.php`**

```
'sqlsrv' => [
        'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
        'host' => "(HOST_ADDR)",
        'port' => "(PORT)",
        'database' => "UNIS",
        'username' => "(USER_NAME)",
        'password' => "(PASSWORD)",
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => false,
    ]
```

Then Add Model connection as

```
protected $connection = 'sqlsrv';
```